# Why am I NOT getting a mutating table error in trigger?

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-11g

It's (or at least was) known that you cannot use DML statements on a mutating table inside a trigger. An excerpt from the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g1699708):

> A mutating table is a table that is being modified by an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT statement, or a table that might be updated by the effects of a DELETE CASCADE constraint.
>
> The session that issued the triggering statement cannot query or modify a mutating table. This restriction prevents a trigger from seeing an inconsistent set of data.

However, I cannot understand why this demo trigger is not failing with a "mutating table" error when I perform an `insert into emp` using SQL Developer or SQL*Plus:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_bri   
  BEFORE INSERT ON emp 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  SELECT max(id) + 1 INTO :NEW.id FROM emp;
  UPDATE emp SET salary = 5000;

END emp_bri;
```

The insertion completes successfully with the next `id` value and updates all `emp` records. I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0. I have read about compound triggers but the sample does not use them.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: do ***NOT*** use `select max(id)` to assign unique numbers. Just don't. It's simply incorrect and it won't scale as well.

Comment: Yes, I know that :) The example is probably not very good in this case... Autoincrement values should be definitely implemented by using sequences and triggers.

Comment: This sure is strange. Btw: here is an SQLFiddle example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e59f/2

Comment: Thanks for sharing info, cool link. Didn't know there's such Oracle SQL testing website :)

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: Another example: [Fiddle-test-2 (SET salary=salary+10)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa6ca/4)

Comment: Auto increment is in Oracle 12. I'll put money on it just being a hidden trigger and sequence behind the scenes. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an exception. When you define a `before insert`, row-level trigger on a table and issue a single row `INSERT` statement, the `table is mutating` error will not be raised. But if you define the same kind of trigger and issue a multi-row `INSERT` statement, the error will be raised. Here is an example:

```
SQL> create table TB_TR_TEST(
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 number
  4  )
  5  ;

Table created

SQL> create or replace trigger TR_TB_TR_TEST
  2  before insert on TB_TR_TEST
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    SELECT max(col1) + 1 INTO :NEW.col1
  6      FROM TB_TR_TEST;
  7    UPDATE TB_TR_TEST SET col2 = 5000;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created
```

Here is a single-row `insert` statement, which won't raise mutating table error:

```
SQL> insert into TB_TR_TEST(col1, col2) values(1,2);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into TB_TR_TEST(col1, col2) values(3,5);

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete
```

Here is a multi-row insert statement, which will raise mutating table error:

```
SQL> insert into TB_TR_TEST(col1, col2)
  2    select 1, 2
  3      from dual;

insert into TB_TR_TEST(col1, col2)
  select 1, 2
    from dual

ORA-04091: table HR.TB_TR_TEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "HR.TR_TB_TR_TEST", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TR_TB_TR_TEST'
```

Comment: That does seem to be the culprit. Do you have an reference in the manual for this behaviour?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if you have access to the support.oracle.com, search for `ID 132569.1` (`ORA-4091 on BEFORE ROW TRIGGER with INSERT .. into SELECT statement`).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting enough this exception seems to be only documented in the 8i (!) manuals: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68003/01_13dbt.htm#376 (the section "*"Mutating and Constraining Tables*") I can't find that statement in the current manuals.