# Will an update in my trigger trigger itself? Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

Here's my PLSQL trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ROOT_CHANGING_TRG 
BEFORE UPDATE OF ROOT_ID,PARENT_PHYS_ID ON UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
var_root number := :new.ROOT_ID;
var_par number := :new.UNIQUE_ID;

BEGIN

UPDATE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN
SET ROOT_ID = var_root
WHERE PARENT_PHYS_ID = var_par;

END;
```

Will this trigger propagate? Like, if it updates a ROOT_ID for another record, will that trigger its own trigger? Further, if it does trigger that, will it use the new ROOT_ID? I want the ROOT_ID to propagate down the tree I've built.

Edit:

How this works is that each record has a unique ID, a parent ID, and a root ID. I basically have a tree, each member of that tree has a root_ID pointing at the unique ID of the root and a parent ID pointing at the one above it. The root's root and parent IDs are its own unique ID.

in the case that a user manually changes a record to point at a new root and parent, I want all the children of that node to have the new root ID. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for the error: table is mutating, trigger may not see new state

Comment: Why is the table denormalized to store the `root_id` for all the child rows?  Why wouldn't the children just point at the parents and then query the `root_id` from the ultimate parent?  How is a `root_id` different than a `parent_id`?  Is that just a node that doesn't have a `parent_id`?  If so, the `root_id` itself would seem redundant-- root nodes would be any node where the `parent_id IS NULL`.

Comment: I want it to be such that someone can find all the records corresponding to a root by querying SELECT * FROM UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN WHERE ROOT_ID = 12345, which will show the record with UNIQUE_ID 12345 and all of it's children, grandchildren, etc.

I considered not having a ROOT_ID, but I'm not sure how I would be able to retrieve the entire tree if I only had PARENT_ID.

Would I be better off doing this with two tables?

Comment: What would I gain from having the root have a null parent and root ID, apart from making the query more complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal would be this one:

```
CREATE TABLE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN (
    PARENT_PHYS_ID NUMBER,
    PHYS_ID        NUMBER CONSTRAINT PHYSICIAN_PK PRIMARY KEY);

ALTER TABLE DPISYS.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN_PARENT_FK 
   FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_PHYS_ID) REFERENCES DPISYS.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN (PHYS_ID);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ROOT_CHANGING_TRG 
    BEFORE UPDATE OF PHYS_ID ON UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
    FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    :NEW.PHYS_ID := :OLD.PHYS_ID;
END;
```

Then the root element(s) is/are the record(s) where `PARENT_PHYS_ID IS NULL`.

For PHYS_ID, resp. PARENT_PHYS_ID you should use a surrogate key, preferable generated from a sequence. In this case there is no reason (and no possibility) to change them ever.

The root Id you could get with this query:

```
SELECT p.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT PHYS_ID AS ROOT_ID
FROM UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN p
START WITH PARENT_PHYS_ID IS NULL 
CONNECT BY PRIOR PHYS_ID = PARENT_PHYS_ID;
```

Comment: I'm confused. What would a query be that would retrieve an entire tree, from root to grand-grand-grand(etc) children with this structure?

Further:
    :NEW.PHYS_ID := :OLD.PHYS_ID;

What does this do?

The point of what I'm doing is that by querying a root_id, I can get all of the results in that tree, because everything in the tree refers to both the parent and the root. I want to make it that when a parent node is assigned to a new root, all the children are assigned to that same root. This doesn't seem to use roots, and I don't really understand what it does at all. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and the query you gave me just returns all the rows in the table.

Comment: Whoops! I understand now, the query is working. I had no idea sql had this functionality. I will try out the trigger.

Would you mind explaining how this stuff is working?

Comment: `:NEW.PHYS_ID := :OLD.PHYS_ID;` means you cannot update this column. Any attempt to update it will keep the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if this was to work, it would generate an infinite loop.  But more than likely, it will throw a mutating table exception first.

What is the problem that you are trying to solve?  A trigger that updates other rows in a table when one row changes is unlikely to be a reasonable solution.  If you have cross-row dependencies, that almost always indicates that you have a normalization issue that should be fixed in the data model rather than being coded around.

Comment: Would it generate an infinite loop? I want it, when I change a record's root, to have all the records with that record as their parent to have that root as well. The new update won't target the same row, right?

Comment: First, it would generate a mutating table exception.  If you worked around the mutating table exception, it would presumably generate an infinite loop.  If the data in one row is dependent upon the keys in a different row, you have a normalization problem that you should be solving.

Comment: How do I solve this normalization problem? This is what the table is for. Should I not have a tree in a database? How else could I represent this?

Comment: In some conditions you don't get the mutating table exception, see here: [Why am I NOT getting a mutating table error in trigger?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, if the trigger on YourTable inserts a row into YourTable as well, then that insertion will fire another instance of the same trigger.

See previous answers at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391081/how-to-fix-oracle-trigger-causing-recursion-issue

Recursion has issues. Yes, I have written recursive code in the distant past, but I do not do it much any more. I suggest that it is often a bad idea to have **triggers recursing**.

Tree structures are just fine of course.  Have you considered writing a stored procedure that would loop through the data set (without using recursion) and updating or inserting the rows appropriate to your goal?

Comment: I don't know how I would do this non-recursively. Whenever a row is changed, I want the children of that row is changed. When those children are changed, I want their children to change. Ad infinitum. Is it even possible to do this non-recursively?

Comment: Sounds like Wernfried may have resolved your problem. Regarding loops: if your environment did not support recursion you would have to write your own procedural code to update children, etc down the stack.  It is quite doable.